# django- how to update using arguments, i can update normally like first assigning,then Model.save

Tags: python, django

Here is my code for saving:

```
keys={"key1","key2"}
mydict={key: value for (key, value) in data.items() if key in keys}
m=Modelname(**mydict)
m.save()
```

Here, `data` is like an array of keys and values. I don't want to save all, only some keys that are available in `keys`. Above save is working and cool, but how to update it? The resources are same but the operation now is update. I know one method:

```
m=Modelname.objects.get(name="ramesh")
m.college = "some other name to update"
m.save()
```

Now it will be updated with the new college name. But how can I do it directly as I have done using save? `data` I specified contains the keys along with the values to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @San4ez proposes is correct.

Keep in mind though that the `.save` method of a Model flushes/rewrites the entire row back at the database even if you want to change only one column/field.

An alternative method that provides better performance and concurrency is by using
the Queryset's `update` method, which only updates the selected columns.

So provided that "name" has a `unique` constraint(so that filter will return only one result).

```
Modelname.objects.filter(name="ramesh").update(**mydict)
```

There is work being done right now so that future versions of django can
provide this functionality on the `.save` method. See more [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4102)

EDIT: Worth noting is the fact that should you choose to use the above method, any post/pre signals won't be emitted by django and generally the `.save` method of the model won't be called, as per django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update).

Answer (score 0):

```
m = Modelname.objects.get(name="ramesh")
for key, value in data.items():
    if key in keys:
        setattr(m, key, value)
m.save()
```